# Are there any methods for using reserved PHP words as controller names in CodeIgniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, reserved-words

Fully understanding the risk, are there any methods for using reserved PHP words as controller names in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0):

You should not use any class names which are names of already declared classes, so CI_Model and PDO would be a bad idea.